# Making GWT RPC calls to an external service for which you don't have code

Tags: gwt, reverse-engineering, rpc

I would like to make a small program that scrapes information from a 3rd-party GWT-enabled website. Is it possible to somehow call this RPC directly? What would I need to reverse-engineer to do this (i.e. hopefully not the entire low-level protocol).

I am hoping I could somehow just call this from within my own server-side GWT or Servlet app.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible... but you would have to go through their code to understand how the serialization/deserialization works.

Classes of interest are

1. RPC.java
2. ClientSerializationStreamWriter -> ServerSerializationStreamReader are the classes involved in making a GWT request.
3. ServerSerializationStreamWriter -> ClientSerializationStreamReader are the classes involved in creating and interpreting a response.

I am trying out a similar thing as an academic project, and I will add more information if I can decipher these classes.

Comment: But he doesn't have access to their code. He's just trying to make GWT-RPC requests against a service running on their server.

Comment: Jason, that would be general GWT code. Sri, that sounds great, please keep up the research.

Comment: Sri, any progress with this project of yours?

Comment: It hasn't progressed as much as I expected, but whatever I have found is available out here - http://code.google.com/p/degwt/

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure GWT makes it difficult to do cross-site requests, for the sake of security.

Any solution you come up with will probably be hacky (*and* not flexible to future changes), and since you're presumably doing it without the consent of the site in question, probably a bad idea to begin with.

Is there some reason you can't ask the site to publish their data using a REST API?

Comment: This is for the Developer Dashboard on the Google Market. They don't mind me scraping it, but they don't have time to make a REST API. There is no robots.txt for this site, so scraping it should be absolutely okay (otherwise the search engines would be in trouble).

Comment: There's a big difference between scraping and trying to make GWT-RPC requests to their services. GWT makes it hard to make a GWT-RPC service public, for security reasons. And when (not if) they change the API of these calls, your app will break. It *may* be possible, but it won't be a good idea.

Comment: I am sorry, I disagree there is a big difference. Google spiders routinely submit automated queries to all sorts of CGI backends and that's how they crawl the deep web. http://glinden.blogspot.com/2007/03/google-and-deep-web.html Please point me to some specific sources that say GWT-RPC is not to be contacted. That, and scraping is always possible through GreaseMonkey on Firefox. It's just a matter of doing it an easier way.